# Remove comments between quotes in String

Tags: java, string

I need to remove comments from a String. Comments are specified using quotes. For example:

```
removeComments("1+4 'sum'").equals("1+4 ");
removeComments("this 'is not a comment").equals("this 'is not a comment");
removeComments("1+4 'sum' 'unclosed comment").equals("1+4  'unclosed comment");
```

I could iterate through the characters of the String, keeping track of the indexes of the quotes, but I would like to know if there is a simpler solution (maybe a regex?)

Comment: Are comments allowed to contain single quotes using an escape mechanism?

Comment: @Nick: that's not allowed. The field is actually a formula field, which will be evaluated. And ' in a formula has no meaning, so no need to have an escape mechanism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

`str = str.replaceAll("\\'.*?\\'", "");`

This will replace the first and the second `'` and *everything* between them with `""` (Thus, will remove them).

---

*Edit*: As stated on the comments, there is no need to backslash the single quote.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes with backslashes.

Comment: @Nick You're right. I figured it out after I wrote the answer (I'll edit it).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to be able to have quotes inside the comment, this will do it:

```
input.replaceAll("'[^']+'", "");
```

It matches a quote, at least one of anything that isn't a quote, then a quote.

[Working example](http://ideone.com/gHIXpI)